# JQuery Validation Logic - if validation is false do something

Tags: jquery

After I run .validate(), I want to do something if the validation fails.

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#ipForm").validate(
               if(not validate){
                        /// do some stuff here ///
                };
               );
   });
```

This code is just a sample of course ..

Comment: I wanted to know how to do a task if any of the validation failed. I did not know the correct syntax. I did receive the code I needed below from 'Patricia' and it worked! - sorry for the bad example in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to check if a form is valid, use the .valid() call.

For Example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm').validate();//sets up the validation

   if($('#myForm').valid()){ //checks if it's valid
      //horray it's valid
   }
   else{
       alert("I'm not valid");
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$(selector).validate({ }).form()) {
  // Do something.
}
```